# Vim - map shell command

Tags: dictionary, vim

I have following instruction in my .vimrc:

```
map t :!../tt <C-R><C-W> <CR><CR>
```

It works quite fine: vim gets word from file and runs `../t word`. But one annoying thing is when the command is run vim returns to shell for a while and then return to file. I don't need to see command output so is it possible to get around this annoying flash?

Comment: What does `$ ../t word` do? What's the output? Do you want to put it in the buffer?

Comment: Why do you remap `t`? This is a useful movement command ...

Answer (score 2):

You can try either

```
nnoremap <silent> t :<C-u>silent !../tt <C-r>=shellescape(expand('<cword>'), 1)<CR><CR><C-l>
```

or

```
nnoremap <silent> t :<C-u>call system('../tt '.shellescape(expand('<cword>')))<CR>
```

or even

```
nnoremap <expr> <silent> t system('../tt '.shellescape(expand('<cword>')))[-1]
```

. Note some things:

1. Don’t use `map` (without `n` and `nore`) unless you have a specific reason. I believe you don’t need this mapping for visual and operator-pending modes (leading `n` restricts mapping to normal mode only) and you also should not want this mapping to be remappable.
2. Use `<C-u>` to discard count you can occasionally type unless you do know you need it (third version uses two hacks that turn mapping to no-op with a side-effect and does not need `<C-u>`).
3. Never forget to escape shell arguments.
4. Version with `silent !` (do not forget space after `silent`, this is why @David Pope’s answer does not work) has `<C-l>` at the end. This is because using `!` will *always* provide access to your terminal and thus redraw is needed after command has run.
5. Versions with `system()` won’t work if you add an argument containing newline, it is a documented bug. If you don’t want to do so (`expand('<cword>')` won’t ever add newline) it is absolutely safe.
6. `t` is a very useful motion. It is better to learn to use it then remap it to something. I suggest `,t` as a lhs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work.

```
map <silent> t :silent!../tt <C-R><C-W> <CR><CR>
```

But I don't have your tt app so I couldn't test for stderr vs. stdout vs. etc.; I have no idea if those matter in vim.

Comment: No it doesn't work. tt is simple bash script. This is its source code:`#!/bin/bash`
`FILE_OF_EX=~/tmp/to_trans`
`echo $1 > $FILE_OF_EX`